# hmac sha1 with salt and hash in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, sha1, hmac, penetration-testing

Now I am doing a penetration testing for my customer.
I have got the administrator's hash(SHA1) ,but i can't decrypt it on the internet, thus I can't access the `/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm`

But he video here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CzXLLZ8ohZU, the author generate a HMAC hash whit the hash found and the salt hidden in the page,and successfully login in the administrator page.

I tried to write a script to do the same thing, but failed. Here is the code:

```
import hmac
import hashlib

digest_1 = hmac.new('salt here','SHA1 hash here',hashlib.sha1)

result =  digest_1.hexdigest()

print result.upper()
```

But I failed!
Does anybody can tell me how to generate a HMAC hash in coldfusion? Much Thanks!

Comment: follow lockdown guide for your CF version to deny access to /cfide/administrator at the web server.

Answer (score 1):

CF 10+:

```
HMac(message, key [,algorithm] [,encoding])
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WS932f2e4c7c04df8f744b691e1353e37d519-8000.html

CF 9 or below:

Crypto.cfc - Crypto / Security Methods For ColdFusion

https://github.com/bennadel/Crypto.cfc

Comment: I have forked and modified Ben's Crypto.cfc for CF8 compatibility at https://github.com/MrRobWad/Crypto8.cfc